# How can I change speed animated object? [JavaScript and Google Maps]

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm creating project "flight controller" in order to pass the subject in my university. I imported Google Maps and I wrote a animated airplane.

```
         var lineCoordinates = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(fromX, fromY),
               new google.maps.LatLng(toX, toY)
          ];
            var lineSymbol = {
            path: //SVG samolotu///,
            scale: 0.5,
            strokeColor: 'black', 
            fillColor: 'black',
            fillOpacity: 1
          };
            var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
               path: lineCoordinates,
            icons: [{
                  icon: lineSymbol,
                  offset: '100%'
                    }],
          });
          line.setMap(map);

            var count = 0;
            window.setInterval(function() {
            count = (count + 1) % 200;
          if(count ==199) stopCircle(line);
            var icons = line.get('icons');
               icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
               line.set('icons', icons);
               },20);
```

But this solution has one defect. All airplane flight the same time, it's not depends on track.I must do that all airplane will have the same speed (not travel time). But If I zoom on my map , the airplane will move faster;) Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

(sorry if I ignore most of your code)

Okay, let's say we move the icon 100 km every second.
The main thing about the solution is this line; it returns a position that is X distance away from a point, along a route:

```
var pos = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(start, newOffset, google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(start, end));
```

Here is an example you can copy/paste as is.  I hope you can use this to do make your project.
If you want diferent speed and interval, look at lines 21 & 22.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps - animated Airline Routes</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      #map_canvas {
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry"></script>
    <script>
    function initialize() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
         zoom: 6,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.5, 4.5),  // Over Belgium
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
      });
      // settings:
      previewInterval = 1000;  
      previewSpeed = 100;  // 100 km (on the map) / interval time

      // these variables will control the moving icon
      var flightPathCoordinates=[
        [4.485600, 50.90098, 20.96801, 52.167250],    // Brussels - Warshau
        [4.485600, 50.90098, -0.454256, 51.470054]    // Brussels - London
      ];
      var flightPathObjects = [];
      var timers = [];
      var markers = [];

      // now we draw flight paths.  notice, the 2 blocks here below can be put in a for-loop
        // first path  (i = 0)
      var path = flightPathCoordinates[0];
      var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(new google.maps.LatLng(path[1], path[0]), new google.maps.LatLng(path[3], path[2]));
      flightPathObjects.push(drawPath(path[0], path[1], path[2], path[3]));  // draw path
      markers.push(drawIcon(0));                                             // set the icon
      animateIcon(0, 0, distance);

        // second path  (i = 1)
      path = flightPathCoordinates[1];
      distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(new google.maps.LatLng(path[1], path[0]), new google.maps.LatLng(path[3], path[2]));
      flightPathObjects.push(drawPath(path[0], path[1], path[2], path[3]));  
      markers.push(drawIcon(1));
      animateIcon(1, 0, distance);


      /**
      *  Draw a flight path
      */
      function drawPath(fromX, fromY, toX, toY) {
        var lineCoordinates = [
          new google.maps.LatLng(fromY, fromX),   // notice: X is along the longitude, Y is along the lattitude
          new google.maps.LatLng(toY, toX)
        ];
        var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: lineCoordinates,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#00FF00',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });
        line.setMap(map);
        return line;
      }
      /**
      *  recursive function.  animates the the icon.
      */
      function animateIcon(i, offset, totalDistance) {
        var newOffset = (offset + previewSpeed * 1000) % totalDistance;  // notice, the "% totalDistance" makes the plane loop.  You could also stop the function if the distance > totalDistance

        var start = new google.maps.LatLng(flightPathCoordinates[i][1], flightPathCoordinates[i][0]);
        var end   = new google.maps.LatLng(flightPathCoordinates[i][3], flightPathCoordinates[i][2]);
        var pos = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(start, newOffset, google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(start, end));
        markers[i].setPosition(pos);

        timers[i] = setTimeout(function () {           // we trigger this function again in 1 second
          animateIcon(i, newOffset, totalDistance)
          }, previewInterval
        );
      }
      /**
      *  sets a marker on the map, at the start of the path
      */
      function drawIcon(i) {
        var start = new google.maps.LatLng(flightPathCoordinates[i][1], flightPathCoordinates[i][0]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: start,
          icon: 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/opensourceicons/32/plane.png',   // you have your own icon ...
          map: map
        });
        return marker;
      }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    //
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```